# Express: Req.body is undefined after POST request

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using the express.bodyParser() before the app.router, and the headers seem to be right, but I'm still getting undefined on req.body:

```
var app = express();
...

app.use(express.bodyParser());
...
app.use(app.router);
```

The output of req.headers is this:

```
{ host: '127.0.0.1:3000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'content-length': '0',
  'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
  accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
  origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.76 Safari/537.36',
  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  referer: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/register',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
  'accept-language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.8' }
```

And the post is declared like this:

```
app.post('/register/do', function(req, res) {
    ...
    console.log(req.headers);
    console.log(req.body);
    ...
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I gave you a plus 1 because I noticed that I wasn't using app.use(express.bodyParser()); in my node app. Totally Fixed My Issue!! Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got `Content-Length: 0`, so the problem is on the client side. Your Express code looks OK.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice that. I had messed up some things with JS and the form wasn't submitting the data properly. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, it happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a alot of problem with this .. this helped me to solve the problem.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
```

var app = express();

```
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
**app.use(bodyParser.json());**
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```